# Using Python Server Process Manager() with Value()

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm using a Server Process to handle shared memory in my program.

```
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
tasksRemaining = manager.list()
sampleFileList = manager.list()
sortedSamples = manager.Value(c_int)
```

I get the following error when trying to declare sortedSamples:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 207, in handle_request
result = func(c, *args, **kwds)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 386, in create
obj = callable(*args, **kwds)
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
```

According to the documentation at https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes, Manager() supports list, dict, Namespace, Lock, RLock, Semaphore, BoundedSemaphore, Condition, Event, Queue, Value and Array.

Whenever I do this outside of a manager, it works fine, such as:

```
sortedSamples = multiprocessing.Value(c_int)
```

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like when you use a manager you need to provide the actual value as well:

> Value(typecode, value) Create an object with a writable value
>   attribute and return a proxy for it.\

(See the documentation for [SyncManager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-managers))

Try doing e.g.:

```
value = manager.Value('i', 0)
```